# AWS IOT Core - expose the tag or name in SQL Query

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-iot, aws-iot-core

I am trying to use some Lorawan sensors through AWS IOT Core. Is there a way to expose the key/value 'tags' or the lorawan device name in the IOT Core SQL for forwarding the message on via MQTT.

For example. The below is the lorawan payload. I'd like to add either the tag / device name to the message. This is unique for each device.

```
tag: "I WANT THIS",
devicename: "OR THIS",
payload: "{"Timestamp":"2022-07-01T05:31:30Z","Payload":"\f�\u0000\u0014\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0001","DevEui":"vsvsv","WirelessDeviceId":"fgvsvs","PayloadData":"DO0AFAAAAAE=","WirelessMetadata":{"LoRaWAN":{"ADR":true,"Bandwidth":125,"ClassB":false,"CodeRate":"4/5","DataRate":"5","DevAddr":"017befe7","DevEui":"a840415a218432f6","FCnt":19377,"FOptLen":0,"FPort":2,"Frequency":"917400000","Gateways":[{"GatewayEui":"vfdvd","Rssi":-75,"Snr":8.75}],"MIC":"68d5805f","MType":"UnconfirmedDataUp","Major":"LoRaWANR1","Modulation":"LORA","PolarizationInversion":false,"SpreadingFactor":7,"Timestamp":"2022-07-01T05:31:30Z"}}}"
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That will not be straightforward as you would need to do a lookup based on the DevEui.
I suggest to create a DynamoDB with an entry for each lorawan sensor, and in iot rule sql query, make a call to that dynamoDB with the devEUI.